# How to copy text element from input into another input by clicking on a checkbox?

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie. I want to copy the input text from shippingName and shippingZip to input text billingName and billingZip if chekbox is clicked. I've tried several things but can't get the result.

Here's my code:

```js
function billingFunction(){
  var shippingName = document.getElementById("shippingName");
  var shippingZip = document.getElementById("shippingZip");
  var billingName = document.getElementById("billingName");
  var billingZip = document.getElementById("billingZip");
  if (document.getElementById("same").checked == true){
    document.getElementById("billingName").value = document.getElementById("billingName").value;
    document.getElementById("billingZip").value = document.getElementById("billingZip").value;
  }
}
```

```html
<form>  
  <fieldset>
  <legend>Shipping Information</legend>     
  <label for ="shippingName">Name:</label>    
  <input type = "text" name = "Name" id = "shippingName" required><br/>

   <label for = "shippingzip">Zip code:</label>    
  <input type = "text" name = "zip" id = "shippingZip" pattern = "[0-9]{5}" required><br/>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="checkbox" id="same" name="same" onchange= "billingFunction()"/>  
  <label for = "same">Is the Billing Information the Same?</label>      
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Billing Information</legend>     
  <label for ="billingName">Name:</label>    
  <input type = "text" name = "Name" id = "billingName" required><br/>

  <label for = "billingzip">Zip code:</label>    
  <input type = "text" name = "zip" id = "billingZip" pattern = "[0-9]{5}" required><br/>
  </fieldset>

  <input type = "submit" value = "Verify"/> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are assigning value from `BillingName` to `BillingName` and `billingZip` to `billingZip` which is empty.

Here is [working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L0dhakjv/) try this JavaScript:

```
function billingFunction() {

  var shippingName = document.getElementById("shippingName");
  var shippingZip = document.getElementById("shippingZip");
  var billingName = document.getElementById("billingName");
  var billingZip = document.getElementById("billingZip");
  if (document.getElementById("same").checked == true) {
    billingName.value = shippingName.value;
    billingZip.value = shippingZip.value;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### 2 thing:

don't compare Booleans variables to Boolean primitives:

```
if(document.getElementById("same").checked == true) //DON'T NEED THIS
```

Just do:

```
if(document.getElementById("same").checked)
```

you repeated `billingZip` and `billingName`. Here:

```
document.getElementById("billingName").value = document.getElementById("billingName").value;
document.getElementById("billingZip").value = document.getElementById("billingZip").value;
```

```js
function billingFunction(){
  var shippingName = document.getElementById("shippingName");
  var shippingZip = document.getElementById("shippingZip");
  var billingName = document.getElementById("billingName");
  var billingZip = document.getElementById("billingZip");
  if (document.getElementById("same").checked){
    document.getElementById("billingName").value = document.getElementById("shippingName").value;
    document.getElementById("billingZip").value = document.getElementById("shippingZip").value;
  }
}
```

```html
<form>  
  <fieldset>
  <legend>Shipping Information</legend>     
  <label for ="shippingName">Name:</label>    
  <input type = "text" name = "Name" id = "shippingName" required><br/>

   <label for = "shippingzip">Zip code:</label>    
  <input type = "text" name = "zip" id = "shippingZip" pattern = "[0-9]{5}" required><br/>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="checkbox" id="same" name="same" onchange= "billingFunction()"/>  
  <label for = "same">Is the Billing Information the Same?</label>      
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Billing Information</legend>     
  <label for ="billingName">Name:</label>    
  <input type = "text" name = "Name" id = "billingName" required><br/>

  <label for = "billingzip">Zip code:</label>    
  <input type = "text" name = "zip" id = "billingZip" pattern = "[0-9]{5}" required><br/>
  </fieldset>

  <input type = "submit" value = "Verify"/> 
</form>
```